# Android - Design trouble - Should I use setTag to hold information for OnClick event?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm doing a small project as part of the Android course.
The app is supposed to retrieve the most popular movies using some site's API and then display them in a grid view (using posters as thumbnails).
When a specific movie is clicked a new activity will be started providing details.

I've gotten this far:

1. Obtained a list of most popular movies poster image URL's using the website's API.
2. Implemented an adapter extending ArrayAdapter which accepts ArrayList as the data source and loads the image from URL into ImageView item.
3. Populated the GridView using the adapter.
4. Setup listeners on Gridview using this code:

s:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
    //do stuff according to position/view
}
```

The info I need to pass onto the movie details activity when a movie is clicked can be obtained in step 1 (I just extracted the poster URLS from the json).
To be able to even provide information when a view is clicked I need to (at the very minimum) also extract the movie's ID and store it.

So as it seems my options are:

1. Store the IDs in the adapter. Then when a click occurs use getItem(position)   to obtain the ID and send it with the intent. The next activity will then have to query the server for the movie details.

This means creating a class:

```
static class MovieItem {
   int Id;
   string posterUrl;
}
```

And converting the adapter to use `ArrayList<MovieItem>`.

2. Same as option 1 but instead use setTag to store the Id of the movie.
3. Same as option 1 but instead obtain all the required information (title, rating, plot, etc..) and store it to MovieItem. Query not required in the next activity.
4. Same as option 3 but instead use setTag (MovieItem). Query not required in the next activity.

I'm new to app development and I'm trying to get things done the right way, Would appreciate some help.

EDIT:
Also wanted to add, if I had stored additional movie information in the adapter would that not have been appropriate because the information isn't relevant to that class?

Thanks for your troubles! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first request the list of Movie info, you could store the details for each movie in something like a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`, where the String is the movie id, and the Map is a set of Key/Value pairs for details information. Then, when a click comes through on your onClick, you would use the position to determine which movie poster was clicked. You would then retrieve the details HashMap for the selected movie, put it into a Bundle, pass it to the Intent of your new Activity, then retrieve it on the other side. So the code would look something like this:

When you first retrieve your list of movies, you would do something like this:

```
//You would put each set of movie data into a HashMap like this...
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> movies = new HashMap<>();

HashMap<String, String> details = new HashMap<>();
details.put("dateReleased", "7.12.2015");
details.put("rating", "PG-13");
details.put("title", "Cool Awesome Movie");
movies.put("12345", details);

//Then when an onClick comes in, you would get the set of 
//details for the movie that was selected (based on position)
HashMap<String, String> selectedDetails = movies.get("12345");

//Put the retrieved HashMap of details into a Bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("movieDetails", selectedDetails);

//Send the bundle over to the new Activity with the intent
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourDetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then when the new Activity starts, you would retrieve the details from the Bundle in your onCreate():

```
 //Then in onCreate() of the new Activity...
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 HashMap<String, String> movieDetails = (HashMap<String, String>) bundle.getSerializable("movieDetails");
 String dateReleased = movieDetails.get("dateReleased");
 String rating = movieDetails.get("rating");
 String title = movieDetails.get("title");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This does seem like a neat alternative, but I was wondering if I had used setTag would that have been a misuse of it?

Comment: Also wanted to add, if I had stored additional movie information in the adapter would that not have been appropriate because the information isn't relevant to that class?
Sorry If I'm being a hassle but I'm looking for answers rather than just 'do this'. Thank you :)

Comment: When you say you want to use setTag(), I'm assuming you mean the setTag() of the ImageView? You could certainly use that to store the id then pass it through with the intent as you mentioned. But! That also means you have to make two url requests, instead of one. If you have a small amount of data (say, a list of like 10 movies), I would probably opt to download all the data at once, then just create details Activities using the stored data. If you had like 100 movies, it would probably be better to fetch the details per-click.

Comment: As for your question about doing all this stuff in your ArrayAdapter, that's really a decision you have to make based on your own preference. You could certainly do all this stuff inside the adapter itself, but I would say most devs would want those server requests in their own class (I know I would). It's usually best practice to keep your classes and methods as small and focused as possible. That's always the better option when it comes to maintaining your own code and tracking down issues.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear earlier, I did mean ImageView.setTag().
I wasn't planning on doing server requests in the adapter but rather just store the additional information when setting/updating the data. The request itself is done outside of it.
As for your solution, I just realized I wouldn't be able to use the position to get the movie clicked because the key for the outer HashMap is the actual movie id where as position is an index.So either way I'd have to either store it using setTag or an array and use position as index.
Anyway thanks a lot for your help, I think I've got this from now

Comment: Well I just used the movie id as an example key. You could also use an [Integer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html) as the key and then use methods like intValue() to compare it to position. But the way I would probably do it is to build your suggested `MovieItem` class and just store any and all information I needed in that class so any movie could provide any information about itself as needed, including its position on the grid.